# Debugging ok on iPhone4 but EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPod Touch and iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipod-touch

I'm developing an app on my Macbook debugging it on my iPhone4. The app make use of camera, internet connections, and normal stuffs.
Today I'm trying to debug it on an iPod Touch 2G and on an iPhone 3G......but it always install the app on the device, it says "running" but before the app il really launched I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".....non message...even NSZombieEnabled didn't work!!

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What is the iOS version on those devices? Also, are you using any iPhone4 specific features?

Answer (score 0):

Check the stacktrace when it crashes then look up the last called function.
It might be a new API function and in that case you must first check for it's existence in the installed iOS version.

Comment: Thank you...but the stack doesn't print nothing....I tried to use NSZombieEnabled to fix it.....but it doesn't print nothing again...

Comment: In the Organizer window I see some Crash log....it says KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE on a unknown thread.

Comment: If you run it in debug mode it should show the stack in the UI at the time of the crash...

Comment: Solved!!!In my project I had a linked library compiled for armv7 (iPhone4) architecture......